# Retrieve Lotus Notes Domino directoy groups and users

Tags: vb.net, directory, lotus-domino

Using Studio 2013 VB.

I am attempting to retrieve group members from our Lotus Notes Domino directory - but I cannot get past this error: "A protocol error occurred. Failed, invalid authentication method specified." I was assuming (maybe incorrectly) that this could be done using DirectorySearcher as we do for our Active Directory.

I have tried retrieving various data with the same results. My research seems to indicate a problem with the ldapsettings but I am using the same alias and specific ldapsettings used by other in-house scripts (albeit written in perl). So the ldapsettings still might be the problem.

The line of code that fails is:

```
Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne
```

The value of searcher.Filter is (&(objectclass=dominoGroup)(cn=mydominogroup))
So this looks like it is build right.

Any help with errors in my code - or even suggestions to accomplish this task a better way are appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
dim grp as String = "mydominogroup"
Using dEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mycompanyldapsettings")
   dEntry.Username = myadminaccount
   dEntry.Password = myadminpassword

   Using searcher As New DirectorySearcher(dEntry)
      searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectclass=dominoGroup)(cn={0}))", grp)
      Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne <--fails here
      If result Is Nothing Then
          "report group not found"
      Else
           Dim members As Object = result.GetDirectoryEntry.Invoke("Members", Nothing)
           If members Is Nothing Then
               "report no members found in group"
           Else
               For Each member As Object In CType(members, IEnumerable)
                  Dim currentMember As New DirectoryEntry(member)
                  If currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower = "user" Then
                        Dim props As PropertyCollection = currentMember.Properties
                        "get and list the user pros("someattribute").Value)"
                  End If
               Next
           End If
      End If
   End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the Domino LDAP service with an LDAP client, with the same credentials (specified in the exact same format as you are using in your actual code) and doing the same query? I like the SoftTerra client myself, but there's even a simple command line client included with the Domino server. Do you know for sure that the Domino LDAP service is even running?

Comment: Yes I do suspect the protocol issue is with the connection itself. Do you see any other errors in the code that would cause this type of protocol error?

Comment: I've not used these particular classes, so I'm not really the right one to look at the code -- or guess what app configuration data it's dependent on. The very first thing I'd do, though, is try the connection and query from a stand-alone client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to call an external Process to solve this.